# 8 bit floating point binary to decimal

Tags: floating-point, 32-bit, floating-point-conversion

This question is similar to the question asked here: [Floating point conversion for 8-bit floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691199/floating-point-conversion-for-8-bit-floating-point-numbers). The marked answer is good but I am missing what a few of the symbols mean and some of the math completed in between the lines. If you could, please walk me through the process for converting the following 8-bit binary floating point to it's decimal counterpart with IEEE 754-2008.

Where is this formula derived and what are the variables in this formula, specifically `2**`:

```
bias = emax = 2**(k - p - 1) - 1
```

Please show me the steps with math to convert `0010 0110` to it's decimal representation.

Comment: You're going to need to know what format is being used.  Saying "IEEE 754" isn't enough: IEEE 754-2008 doesn't specify an 8-bit binary floating-point format.  It's possible to describe 8-bit formats in the *style* of IEEE 754, but there are still some parameters you'd have to specify in that case.  So whoever gave you those 8 bits is also responsible for telling you what format they're supposed to be in; without that information, there's no way to interpret those bits.

Answer (score -1):

I found this webpage with a detailed explanation on how to make the conversion:

http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/flt/ftod.html

The following is a copy-paste of one 8-bit example that breaks the binary string as `0 010 0110`:

```
Convert the 8-bit floating point number 26 (in hex) to decimal.
Convert and separate: 2616 = 00100110 2
Exponent: 0102 = 210; 2 − 3 = -1.
Denormalize: 1.0112 × 2-1 = 0.1011.
Convert:
Exponents   20      2-1     2-2     2-3     2-4
Place Values    1       0.5     0.25        0.125       0.0625
Bits    0   .   1       0       1       1
Value           0.5         +   0.125   +   0.0625  =   0.6875
Sign: positive
Result: 26 is 0.6875.
```

Comment: Exponent 010 will be -2 not -1